# Domestic Or International Check In

Tags: transit

If I'm traveling from a US city to a Canadian city but with a change of planes in another US city would I check in for the first  flight internationally or would check in be a typical domestic check in?

Comment: Is there any situation where check-in differs significantly between a domestic and an international flight? Only difference I can see is that for an international flight they may check that you have the correct visa for your destination/transits.

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen separate "domestic" and "international" check-in areas or procedures, including in situations similar to OP where I took a domestic US flight followed by an international one out of the US. Everybody checks in for the first flight in the same way, regardless of any subsequent connecting flights they may or may not have.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone will be called to the gate agent for passport check before boarding the Canadian plane. It can't really be done before; there are no airports with dedicated transit areas in the USA.

Comment: The only entity checking the passport will be the airline.  They can do that when you check in for your first flight.

Comment: And yet, they will call you to the gate agent for a passport check because they have no way to know who is in the terminal coming from where. At least that's how it was at... huh, a lot of aiports :)

Comment: As far as I remember, the last time I flew internationally with a domestic connection, I had to fill out a form with my next of kin because I am a US citizen.  Non-US passengers did not need to do this.  Before that requirement started, there was no passport check in the transfer airport.  The visa and passport check happened at check-in, because, after all, the airline does not want to fly you from, say, Pittsburgh to JFK only to find out in New York that you don't have the proper documents to enter Senegal.

Answer (score 1):

Most airports have a single check in counter, but some larger hubs may have separate counters for domestic and international check in.

As your final destination is outside the USA you would check in as an international passenger.  They will usually check your passport when you check in and drop your bags unless you check in online and don't check any bags.  If you do the online check in, then the gate agent for the international flight will ask to verify your passport.

Comment: Can you give us an example for such? Because I can't think of any US airport/airline which has a separate check in like that.

Comment: @chx in some airports, international flights are in a different terminal than domestic flights, at least for some airlines.

Comment: That is true and yet, can you give me an example where you show up at, say, an United desk and you are told, you can't check in here? From what I remember I have checked in at the "wrong" terminal at SFO and JFK both.

Comment: @chx I have learned the hard way that I need to be very careful to go to the correct terminal at both JFK and La Guardia.  In all cases, I was required to go to the terminal from which my flight was departing before I could check in.  Otherwise, the airline would be transporting bags back and forth between terminals because of people like me who show up at the wrong one.

Comment: @chx - Atlanta has separate domestic and international check in areas.